# Embed a responsive youtube video in a frame?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, youtube-api, youtube-iframe-api

Firstly, here's a CodePen link to an example of the issue: http://codepen.io/Siyfion/full/sphCn

And the code itself: http://codepen.io/Siyfion/pen/sphCn

I have an iPad SVG image with a cut-out in the centre that I want to place a YouTube embedded video inside. The problem I have is that the image is in a Bootstrap responsive grid which means that it'll change size depending on the device's width/height.

I've tried using percentage-based offsets to position and size the embedded video within. But for whatever reason it seems that it's not working as the video shrinks in relation to the cut-out when resized, leaving a white "gap" visible.

```css
#iPadFrame {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#iPadContent {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 78.4%;     
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
}

#iPadContent > iFrame {
  position: absolute;     
  top: 11.4%;
  left: 11.9%;
  width: 80.5%;
  height: 76.8%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1" id="movieSection">    
      <img id="iPadFrame" src="http://www.labellogiclive.com/images/af4f79b4.iPad.svg" alt="iPad Video Frame">
      <div id="iPadContent">
        <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/89OduOlMc0M?rel=0;showinfo=0;cc_load_policy=0;modestbranding=0;vq=hd720" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your question please

Comment: please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913781/embed-youtube-video-inside-image